# Example for MuPDF using OpenSSL

Tags: pdf, openssl, digital-signature, mupdf

I am trying to generate MuPDF with integrated OpenSSL support and looking for examples which did that already.

All downloads of MuPDF (open source freeware versions) **do not contain** OpenSSL as a thirdparty product - in contrast to a handful of other freewares.
However, the PDF signing feature is implemented and it seems it could be easily activated - provided an OpenSSL installation is ***properly integrated*** with it when building MuPDF.

**Did anyone do this already?**

Note: the Windows CLI tools do support the "sign" function (`mutool sign ...`), and you can e.g. remove signatures. But signing and verifying do not work complaining about **missing OpenSSL support**.

Answer (score 0):

> All downloads of MuPDF (open source freeware versions) do not contain OpenSSL as a thirdparty product - in contrast to a handful of other freewares.

I've no idea what you're trying to get at. Hardly anyone redistributes the OpenSSL source code. It's available on https://www.openssl.org

> Note: the Windows CLI tools do support the "sign" function (mutool sign ...), and you can e.g. remove signatures. But signing and verifying do not work complaining about missing OpenSSL support.

Whatever ones you're running were built without openssl support enabled. You can just build them with it enabled.

On linux that's just a matter of having openssl installed and running 'make', it's all "properly integrated", you just have to have openssl available.

On windows it's a bit more involved as always, but I believe that's a matter of selecting the right configuration in Visual Studio (e.g. "ReleaseOpenSSL"), and having openssl available.